# Return error message in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS. I'm looking the tutorial - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

On submit the script read JSON from the server:

```
handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    comments.push(comment);
    this.setState({data: comments}, function() {
      // `setState` accepts a callback. To avoid (improbable) race condition,
      // `we'll send the ajax request right after we optimistically set the new
      // `state.
      $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: comment,
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    });
  },
```

And update `data`. How can I send error message from JSON? Something like this:

```
<Comment author={comment.author} key={index}>
    {comment.text}
    <div class="error">Error</div>
</Comment>
```

Should I set it in `data`:
`this.setState({[{name: 'John', text: 'text', error: 'error'}]});`

And change comments?:

```
<Comment author={comment.author} key={index}>
    {comment.text}
    <div class="error">{comment.error}</div>
</Comment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see here, the error returned would be request-specific, not comment-specific. In that paradigm it wouldn't make sense to give each comment an error property. Instead, in this situation I'd keep some sort of array to store the errors:

```
this.setState({
  errors: this.errors.push(err);
});
```

Then you can have a separate `<ErrorDisplay/>` component of your own creation which receives the error array as a prop. Whenever the array changes, perhaps it can display the most recent error for a few seconds. It's up to you.

By the way, dig into [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) as soon as you can. If not Flux, then something else. The folks at Facebook will eagerly tell you that keeping definitive state like this in a React component is to be avoided. It's a necessary evil when getting acquainted with React though, so don't worry.

Comment: Thank you. "If not Flux, then something else". What can you advice?

Comment: Some people combine Angular with React too. My point there is that once you're using React in a real application, make sure it only handles the View and leave the data/model/control/etc to other agents. To be partial, I highly recommend Flux. Fluxible (from Yahoo) and Reflux are two excellent implementations of the Flux paradigm. Check them out on GitHub.

Comment: @NickBolsh [Here's an example of a Fluxible app](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/tree/master/react-router) using react-router for the routing. Everything view related is React components, while the state and logic is handled in a Flux fashion.

Comment: here is 8 no-flux strats for communication: http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/ one of which you can use is something called an Observer Pattern (PubSubJS), which is what I use.